# How to remove all content from folder but not a folder with all content in subfolder

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with this structure

```
MyFolder
|----File1
|----File2
|----File...
|----SubFolder01
|----SubFolder02
|----SubFolder...
|----ImportantSubFolder
        |----VeryImportantSubSubFolder
               |----ImportantFile01
               |----ImportantFile02
               |----ImportantFile...
               |----ImportantFolder01...
               |----ImportantFolder...
```

And I need to delete all content in "MyFolder" but not "VeryImportantSubSubFolder" including all files/folders in this "VeryImportantSubSubFolder"

So after deleteing I need only

```
MyFolder
|----ImportantSubFolder
        |----VeryImportantSubSubFolder
               |----ImportantFile01
               |----ImportantFile02
               |----ImportantFile...
               |----ImportantFolder01...
               |----ImportantFolder...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$folder = 'C:\myfolder\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | ForEach-Object {

    if( !$_.PSIsContainer ) {
        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force | Out-Null
    }
}
```